# Как контроллеры MVC вызывают несколько разных сущностей (компонентов, элементов, модулей)?

Tags: веб-программирование, mvc, проектирование, php

Не первый год программирую, но не могу понять одну простую вещь: как контроллеры MVC формируют многофункциональные страницы. Например, на странице на этом сайте есть верхний тулбар, меню справа, меню футреа, основной контент и т.д.

Мне гораздо легче дается понимание HMVC, то есть компонентного подхода. Там все просто: в шаблоне вызываем нужный компонент, и он уже работает как замкнутая система со своим внутренним MVC.

Буду признателен, если кто-то сможет втолковать идею. Сколько статей не прочитал, так и не понял этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класическое mvc это когда представление по событию модели берет из неё положенное интерфейсом, диспатчит контроллеру, а контроллер меняет модель. Стоит заострить внимание, что контроллер не меняет представление вообще ( хотя в классике это ДОПУСКАЕТСЯ ), а модель меняет так, что решение меняться или нет остается за моделью. И такая модель называется "активной" и при ней контроллер "тонким", что является единственно верным вариантом. ВСЁ!

Остальное это неправильно и ложно. Но чья-то глупость распространилась так, что даже гуру не верят в первоисточник, хотя wiki и "gof" об это говорят прямо (и причиной такой mvc-ериси, как я считаю, стало опускание из контекста статьи контроллера).

**Обновление**

Контроллер служит связующим звеном между представлением и модель. Но дело в том, что в wiki и всяких статейках приводятся (если и правильные реализации) минимальные примеры, которые в жизни не существуют. И ещё уясните одну маленькую и ускользающую от всех деталь - представление не имеет ссылку на модель, представление имеет ссылку на реализацию интерфейса. То есть, по ооп, структура строится на интерфейсах, модель это абстракция, а не живой объект. И когда все слюнями плюются и говорят, что представление имея ссылку на модель, нарушает концепцию о разделении логики от отображения, то просто говорящие не углублялись в mvc сильно, а используют навязываемые фраймворки, которые делают люди, но их концепцию обожествляют и выставляют эталоном.

Comment: @vas да я тоже обращал на это внимание в википедии, но тогда я вообще не могу понять, в чем смысл контроллера?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

MVC была разработана в 1979 году, когда дела шли немного по-другому (меня тогда еще не было на этом свете, но, подозреваю, каждое окно ограничивалось ровно одной функцией), и предназначалась она не для веба. MVC используют просто потому, что она позволяет избавиться от загаживания кода, следуя простому паттерну, и многие вещи делаются в обход парадигмы, например, каждый виджет (например, меню страниц) должен был бы получить данные от контроллера, но наверняка подтягивает их сам из модели. Скажем так, это нестрогое MVC.
HMVC и мне импонирует больше MVC.

"предназначалась она не для веба" = не то чтобы она плохо подходит вебу, просто когда концепция была озвучена, никто и не думал, подойдет ли это для php-фреймворка.

Comment: @Etki да я вот тоже уже читал от многих людей, что HMVC в плане веба им нравится больше, но все же создаются же фреймворки на mvc (типа laravel) - поэтому чисто в образовательных целях хотелочь бы понять и хоть немного разобраться в этой архитектуре.

Comment: Только немного по другому, "нестрогое" MVC - это обработка через контроллер моделей и впихивание их в виев, а вот правильное MVC, что оглашается паттерном - там вьювка работает с моделью, а контроллер получает инструкции.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, насколько я понимаю: при заходе на страничку контроллер получает набор инструкций, (вывести меню, вывести контент и т.д.), он посылает эти инструкции по своим модулям, те, в свою очередь, обрабатывают инстукции, из вьювок берут инфу о том, КАК нужно вывести, и выводят каждый по отдельности.

Но чаще всего все пишут так: контроллер получает функции, и контроллер САМ работает с модулями и вьюхами, т.е. модуль выступает в роли класса определенной сущности, где с помощью методов контроллер получает необходимую инфу, сам загружает вьюху и сам их соединяет.